# Using JQuery plugins or libraries which are not in NPM in Aurelia CLI application

Tags: jquery, plugins, aurelia

I'm new to aurelia and trying to add [JQuery Popup Overlay](http://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/) to my Aurelia CLI v 0.23.0 project (typescript). This library is not available in NPM. can anyone guide me on what is the proper way to use it in my project and add it aurelia.json.

What if the library got CSS and image resources as well.

unfortunately i couldn't find any proper structured and clean way to do it, or a tutorial or documentation. in [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/6) there is a documentation but that's for the client libraries which are available on npm. appreciate you guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **aurelia.json** you can add libraries that come from anywhere. Since your library is not in NPM, you will have to copy its folder to your project folder, and then add the instruction in the **aurelia.json**. For example:

```
{
  "name": "JQueryPopup",
  "path": "../JQueryPopup", //<--- folder path
  "main": "jquery-popup", //<--- filename without .js
  "resources": [
    "file1.css", //<-- css resources
    "file2.css"
  ]
}
```

However, sometimes the best way to handle legacy libraries is adding `<script>` and `<link>` tags to your **index.html**. I think this would be the best option considering that this library is not even in NPM.

Comment: Thanks Fabio, when i try to use the first method the compiler returns :  error TS2307: Cannot find module ''jquerypopup".

 I have set the "path" and "main" correctly . the library has no other resources. Tracing jquerypopup also passes with no error but when i wanna import the module it return error. im importing in this way : import {jquerypopup} from 'jquerypopup'; 
i have tried other importing syntaxes as well but seem aurelia cant find the module.

Comment: The right syntax would be just `import 'jquerypopup';`. Sometimes import is not necessary. Try to call your jquery method without importing the library, using `$('#something').jquerypopup()`

Comment: I tried importing using this way, however I was getting 'jQuery is not defined' , i have added the jquery as 'deps', not working , i added the jquery.js in 'prepend' , but now im getting `$(...).popup is not a function. seems the dependencies wont set properly in this way. maybe at the moment as you mentioned the answer would be using the <script> tag for libraries which are not in npm (however that would be kinda messy). I check your second solution as the answer for current version of aurelia (0.23.0). Thanks :)